# Login em PHP com niveis de permissão

Tags: php, sql, session, select

Estou com um problema no meu código para separar os logins. Quero que quando é inserido um login com o `Rank = 1` ele redirecione para uma página, e quando o `Rank` é `= 0` vá para outra. Tentei fazer mas não tive resultado porque ele manda sempre para a mesma. Como resolver isso?

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';

$userName = $_POST["user-name"];
$userPass = $_POST["user-pass"];
$criptSen = hash("whirlpool", $userPass);
@$rediURL = $_GET["url"];

$SQL = mysql_query("SELECT Usuario, Senha FROM utilizadores WHERE Usuario='$userName'         AND Senha='$criptSen'");
        $query = mysql_query($SQL);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            $rank = $row["Rank"];
        }
if(mysql_num_rows($SQL) != 0){

session_start();

$_SESSION['Usuario'] = $userName;
$_SESSION['Senha']   = $criptSen;

if($rank = 0){
  header("Location: membro.php");   
} elseif($rank = 1) {
     header("Location: admin/index.php");   
}   
} else {
header("Location: index.php");
}
?>
```

Código para proteger Páginas Internas `Rank = 1`

```
@$Usuario = $_SESSION["Usuario"];
@$Rank   = $_SESSION['Rank']

if(!(isset($Usuario) && isset($Senha))){

$url = explode("/", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);

header("Location: index1.php?url=$url[3]");

} else if(isset($Usuario) && isset($Senha)){

$SQL = mysql_query("SELECT Usuario, Senha FROM utilizadores WHERE     Usuario='$Usuario' AND Senha='$Senha' AND Rank=1");

if(mysql_num_rows($SQL) == 0){

    echo "<script>alert(\"Area Restrita\");</scrpit>";
    header("Location: ../index.php");
} 
}
?>
```

Comment: a alteração funcionou?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Normalização do Código PHP da Pergunta

_Obs: **mysql__*** está obsoleta nas novas versões do PHP, então, esse código poderia ser colocado em [Mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) ou [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php), mas, fiz acompanhando a pergunta

**Erros Encontrados:**

```
$userName = $_POST["user-name"];
$userPass = $_POST["user-pass"];
@$rediURL = $_GET["url"];
```

> *Não usou [isset](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) para testar o $_POST e $_GET*, e a melhor prática seria utilizar [filter_input](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input.php).

---

```
$SQL = mysql_query("SELECT Usuario, Senha FROM utilizadores WHERE Usuario='$userName'         AND Senha='$criptSen'");    
$query = mysql_query($SQL);
```

> *Perceba que ele fez mysql_query 2 vezes !!!*

---

```
$rank = $row["Rank"];
```

> *Perceba que ele queria pegar o Rank sem chamar na SQL*

---

```
if($rank = 0){
  header("Location: membro.php");
} elseif($rank = 1) {
     header("Location: admin/index.php");
}
```

> *Fez comparação $rank com apenas 1 igual, comparação são 2 iguais ou 3 se quiser além de testar o valor o seu tipo*

---

```
$_SESSION['Usuario'] = $userName;
$_SESSION['Senha']   = $criptSen;
```

> *Guardou a senha na Session, por qual motivo, isso não seria falha de segurança?*

---

## Código Normalizado

```
<?php
    require_once    'config.php';

    $userName = isset($_POST["user-name"]) ? $_POST["user-name"]: '0';
    $userPass = isset($_POST["user-pass"]) ? $_POST["user-pass"]: '0';

    if ($userName != '0' && $userPass != '0'){

        $criptSen = hash("whirlpool", $userPass);
        $rediURL  = isset($_GET["url"]) ? $_GET["url"]: ''; 

        $SQL = "SELECT Usuario, Senha, Rank FROM utilizadores WHERE Usuario='$userName' AND Senha='$criptSen' limit 1";
        $query = mysql_query($SQL);

        if (mysql_num_rows($query)>0)
        {
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
            $_SESSION['Usuario'] = $row['Usuario'];     
            $_SESSION['Rank']    = $row['Rank'];
            mysql_free_result($query);

            if($row['Rank'] == 0){
                header("Location: membro.php");
            } else {
                if($row['Rank'] == 1) {
                    header("Location: admin/index.php");                
                }
            }       

        } else {
            if (isset($query)){
                mysql_free_result($query);
            }
            header('location: index.php');      
        }   

    } else {
        header('location: index.php');
    }
?>
```

## Porque eu guardei o Rank em uma Session?

Para que seja feito o teste no carregamentos das páginas e conferir se tal usuário tem permissão de visualizar a página.

## Normalização Página Seguinte

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $Usuario = isset($_SESSION["Usuario"]) ? $_SESSION["Usuario"]: '';
    $Rank    = isset($_SESSION['Rank'])    ? $_SESSION['Rank']   : '';

    if ($Usuario != '' && $Rank == 1){  
        //AUTORIZADO
        //AQUI ELE TA COM O Rank = 1 e logado com Usuario
    } 
    else 
    {
        //NÃO AUTORIZADO
        echo "<script>alert(\"Area Restrita\");</scrpit>";
        header("Location: ../index.php");   
    }
```

*Obs: Perceba que agora você não precisa acessar novamente a base, porque, o `$Rank` está na [$_SESSION](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) que você pode recuperar, podendo usar esse modelo para as diversas páginas do seu sistema. Outra observação, é não utilizar `script` (javascript) no meio do [PHP](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Php), talvez redirecionar pra uma página é bem melhor, com mensagens que o mesmo não é autorizado*

Comment: Muito obrigado FCCDias. Só que agora o código que eu tinha para proteger todas as páginas do backoffice deve estar errado, eu vou posta-lo no tópico principal para que me ajude se possível a coloca-lo correcto, tal como esse que me forneceu.

Comment: @LuisMiguelGT, por nada...

Comment: Muito obrigado FCCDias, funcionou tudo impecavelmente bem!

Comment: Nunca tinha visto algo como esse post, muito bem estruturado e com explicações claras e objetivas, parabéns @user6026.

Comment: Hey! Essa pergunta caiu do céu, era exatamente a minha dúvida. Tentei usar seu código alterando alguns detalhes pra se adaptar ao que eu tinha pronto e bom, redireciona pra mesma página. Será que dá pra me ajudar?

Answer (score 5):

O seu `SELECT` retorna os campos `Usuario, Senha`, no entanto você tenta pegar `$row["Rank"]`. Altere o SELECT para:

```
$SQL = mysql_query("SELECT Usuario, Senha, Rank FROM utilizadores WHERE Usuario='$userName' AND Senha='$criptSen'");
```

Faça esta alteração da comparação (`==`) ao invés de somente `=`

```
if($rank == 0){

  header("Location: membro.php");

} elseif($rank == 1) {

     header("Location: admin/index.php");

}
```

Comment: Eu ja tinha alterado isso Lucas, não funcionou na mesma.. :S

Comment: @LuisMiguelGT Fiz uma alteração na resposta. Veja se funciona.

Comment: @LuisMiguelGT Sempre que você quiser dizer algo sobre uma resposta, utilize os comentários ao invés de criar uma nova resposta

Answer (score 3):

O erro está no `=` o correto é `==`.

```
if($rank == 0)
{
  header("Location: membro.php");
} 
elseif($rank == 1) 
{
  header("Location: admin/index.php");
}
```

Veja [**Operadores de comparação**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) no *php.net*.

Answer (score 2):

Não vou sugerir colocar em OO porque parece que já está encaminhado, então seguindo a estrutura atual, pelo menos cria uma função para fazer essa verificação nas páginas protegidas e chama essa função, ao invés de repetir o código em todas as páginas.

Outra coisa, a ideia do colega de usar session é boa, mas se for por este caminho guarde uma valor tipo `$_SESSION['login'] = true;` ao invés de guardar a senha na seção, assim você não vai precisar ficar verificando o banco toda hora pra saber se a senha confere.