# Deletar registro pelo ID

Tags: php, mysql

Criei um botão para deletar um registro no banco com o seguinte código:

Arquivo `form.php`:

```
<form action='deletar.php' method='post'>
<input type='submit' name='deletar' value='deletar' />
```

Arquivo `deletar.php`:

```
$del = "DELETE FROM autoriza WHERE ID = '' ";
$delgo = mysql_query($del) or die('Erro ao deletar');
echo "deletado";
```

---

Já tentei algumas alternativas de coletar o ID de cada registro, mas não obtive sucesso.

O que mais encontrei foi criar uma variável ( `$id = $_POST['id'];` ) e usar a variável no comando mysql (`DELETE FROM... ID='$id'`).

Como consigo deletar um registro pela sua ID?

Comment: Funções `mysql_` estão sendo deprecated... Use PDO ou mysqli.

Comment: Como assim, você quer deletar um registro específico sem dizer qual? Pode explicar melhor?

Comment: @bfavaretto: quando o usuário envia um registro pelo form, automaticamente gera um ID. Queria pegar esse ID para colocar DELETAR cada registro.

Comment: @GustavoCave Ainda não está claro... Você quer dizer que acabou de criar um registro, mas não sabe como mandá-lo de volta para o botão de deletar correspondente?

Comment: @bfavaretto exatamente isso!

Comment: Pelo visto você quer saber uma coisa totalmente diferente do que perguntou. A sua pergunta é sobre como passar o id do browser para o servidor. Pelo visto você já sabe fazer isso, e a resposta do FCCDias também explica. Mas o que você quer saber de verdade é como devolver um ID do servidor para o browser logo após a criação de um registro. Nesse caso seria melhor uma pergunta separada (se você mudar esta, invalida as respostas que já tem). Ou entendi tudo errado?

Comment: É isso @bfavaretto. Apenas deletar o registro no qual está sendo solicitado. No caso, usar a ID do registro para deleta-la.

Comment: Eu já consegui fazer deletar pelo ID, mas ele está pegando todas as linhas e então tudo é deletado.

Comment: E também consegui fazer deletar, mas sempre pega o ID menor e então deleta o mesmo, independente de qual eu tentei deletar.

Comment: Sinto muito Gustavo, mas por mais que você explique eu não consigo entender o que você já fez e o que não consegue fazer.

Comment: @bfavaretto sem problemas! agradeço a sua tentativa!

Answer (score 5):

Eu fiz um post para um pergunta [Login em PHP com Níveis de Permissão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13386/login-em-php-com-niveis-de-permissao/13400#13400) que mostra 
como deveria proceder com $*POST, Mysql**, PDO, Mysqli e filter_input para uma melhor segurança, mas, eu fui seguindo seu exemplo com intuito que entenda relação input, form, hidden com PHP. Seria muito legal depois de entender como acontece essa exclusão, que siga para a normalização da codificação, conforme link acima

No form deverá conter o campo `text` ou `hidden` com o valor do código que você deseja mandar para o script `PHP` realizar a tarefa de exclusão via `SQL` banco `MySql`.

No exemplo que estou te passando esse formulário contem um hidden com nome id com value de 1, então, ao clicar no botão deletar ele vai submeter o formulário e executar a SQL de exclusão

```
//Aqui o código id ta fixo (campo hidden)
<form action='deletar.php' method='post'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='1'>
    <input type='submit' name='deletar' value='deletar' />
</form>
```

---

```
//Aqui você digita o código (campo text)
<form action='deletar.php' method='post'>
    <input type='text' name='id' value=''>
    <input type='submit' name='deletar' value='deletar' />
</form>
```

---

```
if (isset($_POST['id'] && is_numeric($_POST['id'])) {
     $del = "DELETE FROM autoriza WHERE ID = " . $_POST['id'];
     $delgo = mysql_query($del) or die('Erro ao deletar');
     echo "deletado";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$del = "DELETE FROM autoriza WHERE ID =".$_POST['id'];
$delgo = mysql_query($del) or die('Erro ao deletar');
echo "deletado";
```

Cria um codição para saber se foi enviado o id, ou use if (isset($_POST['id'].

E use mysqli, pois a mysql_ está sendo descontinuado na nova versão do PHP.