# Login com PHP + MYSQL +MD5

Tags: php, mysql, md5

Criei um formulário de login com o seguinte código:

Login.html:

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value=''>
Usuário<input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" >
Senha<input type="password" name="senha" id="senha">
<input type="submit" name="entrar" id="entrar" value="Entrar">
</form>
```

O código php:

Login.php:

```
<?php
//inclui arquivo com conexao ao banco
include_once('db.php');

$usuario = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['usuario']);
$senha = md5(mysql_real_escape_string(($_POST['senha'])));
$entrar = $_POST['entrar'];
    if ($_POST['entrar']) {

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE usuario='$usuario' AND senha='$senha'" or die("erro ao selecionar");
        $acao_sql = $mysqli->query($sql);

            if ($acao_sql=mysqli_num_rows($sql)>=0){

                setcookie("usuario",$usuario);
                header("Location:painel.php");

            }else{
                echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Login e/ou senha incorretos');window.location.href='login.html';</script>";
                die();

            }
    }
?>
```

O problema é que qualquer senha e usuário que coloco, ele entra no sistema (painel.php).

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13386/login-em-php-com-niveis-de-permissao?rq=1 eu fiz um exemplo bem parecido mas, serve como base!

Comment: Só a jeito de recomendação: não utilizes MD5 porque está mais que provado que não é muito seguro nos dias de hoje - usa outro método de hashing como bcrypt ou, pelo menos, SHA512 com 12 caracteres. Podes sempre melhorar isto com um campo adicional na base de dados, conhecido como SALT, que é gerado de uma forma única e não se repete, aumentado a dificuldade de ataque.

Comment: @mOrSa irei pesquisar sobre isso, agradeço pela dica!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você está usando o [operador de comparação](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.comparison.php) `>= (Maior ou Igual)` no trecho, `mysqli_num_rows($sql) >= 0`, ou seja, se encontrar o usuário `> maior do 0`, se não encontrar, `Igual a 0`, neste caso, seu `if` sempre retorna `true`, e redireciona para `painel.php`.

Além disso você precisa fazer [mysqli_num_rows](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) do `result` da query, ou seja, `$acao_sql->num_rows`.

Edite seu código para:

`if($acao_sql->num_rows == 1)`

ou

`if($acao_sql->num_rows > 0)`

Comment: Já testei assim, occore o seguinte erro: Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_reuslt

Comment: Editei o código, na verdade vc precisa fazer `mysqli_num_rows` do `result`, tente novamente.

Comment: Muito agradecido pelo ajuda!

Comment: É importante usa start_session() para esse tipo de aplicação?

Comment: Sim, é importante e além da dica dada pelo @mOrSa, há outras recomendações importantes a serem seguidas para obter mais segurança, veja algumas neste link: http://pt.wikihow.com/Criar-um-Script-de-Login-Seguro-em-PHP-e-MySQL

Comment: Estou usando o seguinte código para forçar o usuário a logar em determinadas páginas: $login_cookie = $_COOKIE['usuario'];
        if(isset($login_cookie)){
            echo"Bem-Vindo, $login_cookie <br>"; Tem algo errado? Pois não está funcionando.

Comment: Faça, `var_dump($login_cookie); exit;` antes do seu `if` e analise o resultado.

Comment: Resultado: string 'usuario' (length=7)

Comment: Exato, seu script testa `if(isset($login_cookie))`, `isset` testa se a variável foi inicializada, portanto o `if` retorna sempre `true`.

Comment: pelo motivo de retornar sempre true, é o que faz o usuário logado ou não entrar na página?

Comment: Sim, mesmo para usuários que não digitaram corretamente o login e senha você esta inicializando a variável `$login_cookie`.

Comment: Conhece algum material que eu possa seguir para tentar soluiconar?

Answer (score 0):

Se estiver utilizando versão (PHP 5 >= 5.5.0) recomendo fortemente a utilização do [password_hash](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) ou caso seja < 5.5.0, utilizar [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/).