# Redirecionamento Incorreto

Tags: php, mysql, session, login

Estou tentando redirecionar usuários registrados para o painel de controle e os outros visitantes para a página de login, mas recebo esta mensagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Login**

```
<?php
$page = "Login";
include "header.php";

$user_error='';
$pass_error='';

if(isset($_POST["login"])){

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

if(empty($username)){
    $user_error = 'Please insert a username';
}
elseif(!empty($username)){
    $checkusername = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `database`.`user` WHERE `username` = '".$username."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($checkusername) == 0){
        $user_error = 'Wrong username';
    }
}
if(empty($password)){
    $pass_error = 'Please insert a password';
}
elseif(!empty($password)){
    $checkpassword = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `database`.`user` WHERE `username` = '".$username."' AND `password` = '".$password."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($checkpassword) == 0){
        $pass_error = 'Wrong password';
    }
}
}
if(empty($user_error)&& empty($pass_error)&& isset($_POST['login'])){

$login_check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `database`.`user` WHERE `username` = '".$username."' and password = '".$password."'") or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($login_check) == 1){

    setcookie("username",$username);
    $_SESSION['username'];
    $_SESSION['password'];
    header("Location: control-painel.php");
    $logged == 1;
}
 }
     else{
    $user_error = empty($user_error)?'' : htmlEntities($user_error);
    $pass_error = empty($pass_error)?'' : htmlEntities($pass_error);
 ?>

<div id="loginform">
    <form name="loginform" method="post">
        <table cellpadding="0" id="tb">
            <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
            <div class="loginheader">
            <h2>Login</h2>
            </div>
            </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
            <div id="message">
                <?php echo $user_error; ?><br><br>
                <?php echo $pass_error; ?>
            </div>
        <table cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
            <td class="field">Username:</td>
            <td><input type="text" class="text" name="username"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td class="field">Password:</td>
            <td><input type="password" class="text" name="password"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
            <td class="field"></td>
            <td><input type="submit" class="submitbutton" name="login" value="Login"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>

<?php
}
include "footer.php";
?>
```

**Logout**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['logout'])){
session_start();
session_destroy();
header("Location: index.php");
}
?>
```

**Control Painel**

```
<?php
$page = "Control Painel";
include "header.php";

if(!isset($_SESSION['username'], $_SESSION['password'], $logged)){
header("location: control-painel.php");
}
else{
header("location: login.php");
}
?>

<form action="logout.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" class="submitbutton" name="logout" value="Logout"/>
</form>

<?php
include "footer.php";
?>
```

Comment: Já tem resposta nesse link: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13386/login-em-php-com-niveis-de-permissao?rq=1

Comment: Use sessões e criptografe os dados. Dá uma lida no manual sobre sessão.

Comment: Onde eu encontro esse manual?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa rever um pouco melhor a sua lógica.

1. Existem consultas redundantes na página de login.
2. Não é necessário você separar a validação de login da validação de senha, até por questões de segurança (você não quer que um usuário mal intencionado descubra um login válido na sua aplicação certo?).
3. Você também pode usar try/catch para organizar melhor o código.
4. O erro informado está ocorrendo porque a página **control painel** redireciona para ela mesma caso não exista uma sessão. Então não haverá sessão novamente e ela redirecionará de novo para ela mesma. Isso ficará em um loop eterno.

Segue minhas sugestão:

**login.php**

```
$error = '';
if (isset($_REQUEST['login']))
{
    try
    {
        if (empty($_REQUEST['username']))
            throw new Exception('Informe o seu login.');     

        if (empty($_REQUEST['password']))
            throw new Exception('Informe a senha.');     

        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['username']);
        $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['password']);
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `database`.`user` WHERE `username` = '".$username."' AND `password` = '".$password."'");

        if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
             session_start();
             $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
             // Acrescente à sessão outras informações que desejar, mas
             // normalmente o id é a informação principal.

             header('location: control-painel.php');
        }
        else throw new Exception('Login/senha inválidos.');    
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
         $error = $e->getMessage();
    }
}

// A variável $error possuirá o erro (se houver).
// Pra saber se houve erro basta verificar if (!empty($error)){}.
```

**controle-sessao.php**

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['id']))
    header('location: login.php');
```

Em toda página que você deseja controlar o acesso (apenas usuários logados podem acessar) inclua o arquivo 'controle-sessao.php':

**control-painel.php**

```
// Isso precisa estar antes de qualquer conteúdo HTML.
// Recomendo que seja o primeiro comando da página.
require_once 'controle-sessao.php'
```

**logout.php**

```
session_start();
session_destroy();
header('location: login.php');
```

Comment: O código passado é apenas uma orientação. Não testei. Entenda a lógica e aplique ao seu projeto!