# Como aplicar password_hash para uso de SELECT, INSERT e UPDATE?

Tags: php, mysql, hash, senhas

Eu sei que o password_hash funciona assim:

```
string password_hash ( string $password , integer $algo [, array $options ] )
```

**1 -** Mas queria saber como posso aplicar `password_hash` nesses casos:

```
$check = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `database`.`user` 
WHERE `password` = '".$password."'") or die(mysql_error());

$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `database`.`user`(`username`,`password`,`email`)
VALUES ('".$username."','".$password."','".$email."')") or die(mysql_error());

$update = mysql_query("UPDATE `database`.`user` SET `password` = '".$newpassword."' 
WHERE `password` = '".$oldpassword."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

**2 -** Depois de aplicar `password_hash` ainda vou precisar de `mysql_real_escape_string`?

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Antes de mais nada, recomendo leitura desta pergunta:

> [Como fazer hash de senhas de forma segura?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/70)

Seguem dois exemplos de `password_hash` usando `mysqli` e `bind_param`, dispensando a necessidade de se fazer qualquer tipo de *escape* manualmente.

> O `bind param` já faz o escape dos valores automaticamente:

### Exemplo de armazenagem de senha com password_hash:

```php
$mysqli = new mysqli( 'enderecodoservidor', 'usuario', 'senha', 'basededados' );

$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$hash    = password_hash( $_POST['senha'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT );

$query = 'INSERT INTO usuarios ( nome, hash) VALUES ( ?, ? )';
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare( $query );
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $usuario, $hash );
$stmt->execute();
```

### Exemplo de atualização de senha com password_hash:

```php
$mysqli = new mysqli( 'enderecodoservidor', 'usuario', 'senha', 'basededados' );

$usuario = $_session['usuario']; // ou idusuario, depende como voce mantem o login
$hash    = password_hash( $_POST['novaSenha'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT );

$query = 'UPDATE usuarios SET hash= ? WHERE nome = ? '; // ou WHERE id = ?
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare( $query );
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $hash , $usuario ); // ou ("si", $hash, $idUsuario)
$stmt->execute();
```

### Exemplo de verificação de senha com password_hash:

```php
$mysqli = new mysqli( 'enderecodoservidor', 'usuario', 'senha', 'basededados' );

$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$idUsuario = 0; // Isso se trabalhar com ID numérico, o que pode ser interessante

$query = 'SELECT id, hash FROM usuarios WHERE nome = ?';
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare( $query );
$stmt->bind_param("s", $usuario );
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result( $idUsuario, $hash ); // aqui tem que bater com os campos do select
$stmt->fetch();

if ( password_verify( $_POST['senha'], $hash ) ) {
   echo 'Logado';
} else {
   echo 'Usuario e/ou senha invalidos';
}
```

> Deixe um campo varchar() largo o suficiente para o hash da senha, para não correr risco de truncar os dados.

Veja nesse post como atualizar o *hash* das senhas automaticamente com novas versões do PHP:

> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/147319/70

Answer (score 0):

O `password_hash` quem vem no *PHP 5 >= 5.5.0*, poderia ser utilizado assim:

```
$password = password_hash($password);
$check = mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `database`.`user` 
WHERE `password` = '".$password."'") or die(mysql_error());

$password = password_hash($password);
$insert = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `database`.`user`(`username`,`password`,`email`)
VALUES ('".$username."','".$password."','".$email."')") or die(mysql_error());

$password = password_hash($password);
$oldpassword = password_hash($oldpassword);
$update = mysql_query("UPDATE `database`.`user` SET `password` = '".$newpassword."' 
WHERE `password` = '".$oldpassword."'") or die(mysql_error());
```

***Observação:*** No meu entender eu utilizaria [filter_vars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) ou [filter_input](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) no lugar desses [mysql_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) e também em vez de usar o **deprecate** `mysql_*`, usar o [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) ou [Mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php), porque ele será descontinuado nas versões mais novas do [PHP](http://www.php.net), por vários motivos um deles é segurança !!!

Nessa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13386/login-em-php-com-niveis-de-permissao/13400#13400) tem uma boa explicação também sobre a parte do ***Mysql***.