# PHP/Banco de dados, adicionar MD5 e verificar

Tags: php, mysql

Bom, eu uso o código a seguir p/ fazer uma verificação se o usuário existe e iniciar a sessão:

```
<?PHP
include('config.php');
include('menu.php');
# Validar os dados do usuário

function anti_sql_injection($string)
{
    include('config.php');
    $string = stripslashes($string);
    $string = strip_tags($string);
    $string = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao,$string);
    return $string;
}

   $sql = mysqli_query($conexao,"select * from tb_usuario where 
   email_usu='".anti_sql_injection($_POST['email_usu'])."' and 
   senha_usu='".anti_sql_injection($_POST['senha_usu'])."' limit 1") or die("Erro");
$linhas = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
if($linhas == '')
    {
        ?>
        <div class="msg2 padding20">Usuário não encontrado ou usuário e senha inválidos.</div>
        <?PHP
    }
else
    {
        while($dados=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
            {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['nome_usu_sessao'] = $dados['nome_usu'];
                header("Location: conteudo.php");
            }
    }
?>
```

Como podem ver, o código possui uma proteção contra SQLInjection, porém eu gostaria de adicionar encriptação MD5 ou seja verificar a senha com MD5, eu não sei o termo certo p/ isso, mas no caso "ler o MD5".

Comment: Seu código tem umas gambiarras, e não proteção. Sua função anti_injection corrompe caracteres válidos. Só tem que usar `mysqli_real_escape_string()`, mais nada. Outra gambiarra é usar MD5 pra senha. O PHP já possui as funções corretas para isso, que são `password_hash` e `password_verify`.

Comment: Leituras que podem ajudar: [Como aplicar password_hash em SELECT, INSERT e UPDATE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16986/70) e [Como fazer hash de senhas de forma segura?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2402/70), e também [Como prevenir injeção de código SQL no meu código PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/70)

Comment: Vide uma das ultimas respostas do link do fechamento acima para aplicar à leitura do MD5, tem um exemplo prático de select.