# Verificar hash de senha no login (password_hash)

Tags: php, hash

Fiz todo o código de login, porém quando fui testar, deu erro no login, usando a mesma senha que utilizei no cadastro, quando percebi que o **password_hash** sempre gera um hash diferente. Já que sempre é gerado um hash diferente, como verifico esse novo hash com que está salvo no banco? (Estava lendo essa pergunta, mas não me ajudou muito. [Como aplicar password_hash para uso de SELECT, INSERT e UPDATE?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16986/como-aplicar-password-hash-para-uso-de-select-insert-e-update)).

Em uma página de teste coloquei:

```
$senha = password_hash(12345678, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
echo $senha;
// Saiu:
// $2y$10$u5ib0cJivaTMWMceujIAjOq0G8tkjY7UTOMqOnqlWt6Rf8Vb2MLBK
```

Na de login coloquei:

```
$senha = password_hash($senha, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
// mesmo inserindo 12345678 saiu um resultado diferente.
// $2y$10$ZAWmkLhap3LpLH.EtKPl3uUdRV6joyP5sQND1m0HnFH8XNrehazSi
```

formulario:

```
    <form method="post" action="" >
        <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Digite seu nome de usuário"><br>
        <input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Digite sua senha"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="btn" value="Entrar"><br>
    </form>   

    <?php
    // caso haja post, esse if será executado
    if($_POST){
        // Aqui ele vai filtar o post, o ultimo parametro serve para tirar tags e caracteres especiais.
        $usuario = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'usuario', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $senha = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'senha', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        // agora mesmo com esse var_dump está gerando um hash, sendo que eu tirei o password da função
        var_dump($senha);
        // aqui ele inclui a classe
        require_once '../PDO/metodospdo.php';
        // aqui ele chama o método Login, por ser static não precisa criar um objeto.
        MetodosPDO::login($usuario, $senha);
    }
    ?>
```

função completa:

```
static function login($usuario, $senha) {
    try {
        $con = ConnectionFactory::getConnection();
        $con->beginTransaction();
        //$senha = password_hash($senha, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $stmt = $con->prepare("select usuario from tbl_login where usuario = :usuario and senha = :senha");
        $stmt->bindParam('usuario', $usuario);
        $stmt->bindParam('senha', $senha);
        $stmt->execute();
        if ($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo '<script> confirm("Bem vindo ao sistema!"); <script>';
            header("Location: menu.php");
        } else {
            echo '<script> alert("Usuário ou senha incorretos!");
                           window.location("login.php"); </script>';
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: Então, tentei por '12345678', porém continuou com a mesma coisa...

Comment: Faça um `var_dump($senha);`  no segundo código para ver se o valor de senha esta correto.

Comment: Sim, o valor que está entrando tá certo..

Comment: Posta o resultado, de repente você não notou algo. Presumo que $senha venha de um $_POST.

Comment: Atualizei e coloquei os códigos.

Comment: tente utilizar md5 ao inves de password_hash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando usa o password_hash você precisa do password_verify para verificar a senha.

O password_verify precisa do primeiro parâmetro a senha digitada pelo usuário e o outro o hash que está no banco.

Lembrando que o password_verify sempre retorna um valor booleano, e então você pode fazer a checagem facilmente.

[Veja aqui em detalhes](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.password-verify.php)

Comment: Obrigado, resolveu o problema aqui, e o código ficou bem melhor.

Comment: De nada, que bom que ajudou.