# Cadastrando senha 123 com criptografia no MYSQL, mas só faz login com a senha gerada pela criptografia

Tags: php, html, mysql, hash

Eu não sou nenhum expert em PHP, SQL ou HTML, mas eu sou bom em copiar as coisa e transforma-las em algo divertido. Então recentemente fui fazer um site, pra passar o tempo, e eu queria que as senhas cadastradas no banco de dados fossem criptografadas, consegui, mas na hora de fazer o login ela só reconhece a senha criptografada e não a senha que eu uso para teste (123). Gostaria de saber o que ta faltando pra senha logar normalmente. Desde já, agradeço.

**connect.php** : Faz conexão com o host

```html
<?php
//arquivo de conexão com o banco de dados
//mysql_connect
//mysqli_connect
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$db = "db_sitephp";

$link = "mysqli_connect"($host,$user,$pass,$db);
/*$banco = "mysqli_connect_errno"(); //erro de conexão
if($banco == true) {
    echo "Erro de conexão";
}   else{
    echo "Conexão ok";
}*/


?>
```

**cadastrar.php** : Observem o $encrypth

```html
<?php
//arquivo de cadastro

//-------------------------------------------Incluindo o arquivo de conexão
include "connect.php";
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

//-------------------------------------------Recebendo valores da variavel
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];
$resenha = $_POST['repetesenha'];
$lembrete = $_POST['lembrete'];
$foto = $_FILES['foto']['name'];
$tipo = $_FILES['foto']['type'];


//-------------------------------------------Criptografia
$encrypth = password_hash ($senha, PASSWORD_ARGON2I);

//-------------------------------------------Ver se o usuario está habilitado pra fazer o cadastro
$registro = false;
if ($nome != "" && $email != "" && $senha != "" && $lembrete != "" && $foto != "") {

    if ($senha != $resenha) {
        echo "<script>alert('Senhas diferentes');window.history.go(-1);</script>";
    } else {
            //Habilitanto o usuario para o cadastro
        $registro = true;
    }
} else {
    echo "<script>alert('É necessário preencher todos os campos');window.history.go(-1);</script>";
}


//--------------------------------------------Fazendo uma consulta
$sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM tb_user order by id_user desc limit 1 ");
while ($line = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $id = $line['id_user'];
    $email_user = $line['email']; 
}


//--------------------------------------------Criação da pasta de foto do usuario
$id = $id + 1;
$pasta = "user" . $id; //nunca recebera um id igual ao registrado (recebe +1)


//--------------------------------------------verificando existencia da pasta 
if (file_exists("user/" . $pasta)) {
    //echo "<script>alert('Esta pasta já existe');</script>";
    //rmdir($pasta); //apaga pasta
} else {
    mkdir("user/" . $pasta, 0777);
    //echo "<script>alert('A pasta " . $pasta . " foi criada com sucesso');</script>";
}

//----------------------------------------------substituindo characters indesejados
include "substituicao.php";

//---------------------------------------------Formato de arquivo da foto
$formatos = array(1 => 'image/png', 2 => 'image/jpg', 3 => 'image/jpeg', 4 => 'image/gif');
$teste = array_search($tipo, $formatos);
if ($teste == true) {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'], "user/" . $pasta . "/" . $foto);
} else {
    echo "<script>alert('O tipo de arquivo não é suportado');</script>";
}

//----------------------------------------------Recebendo data e hora do computador
$dt = date ('Y-m-d');
$hr = date ('H:i:s');

//----------------------------------------------CADASTRANDO NOVO USUARIO
if($registro == true && $email != $email_user){ 
    mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO  tb_user (nome,email,senha,lembrete,foto,nivel,dt,hr)VALUES 
    ('$nome','$email','$encrypth','$lembrete','$foto',5,'$dt','$hr')");
    echo "<p style='text-align:center;color:#333;padding:5px;'>Usuario cadastrado com sucesso<br>";
    echo "<a href = 'index.php' style='color:#59f'>Ir para Home</a> | <a href= 'login.php' style = 'color:#59f'>Login</a>";
    echo "</p>";
    echo "<p>$senha, $encrypth</p>";//senha passando em 123, enrypth passando criptografado
}else{
    echo "<script>window.history.go(-1);</script>";
}
?>
```

**logar.php** É aqui que eu não consigo passar a senha 123

```html
<?php
include "connect.php";
$email = $_POST ['email'];
$senha = $_POST ['senha'];
if ($email != "" && $senha !=""){
    //echo "Usuario esta logado";
    $sql = mysqli_query ($link, "SELECT * FROM tb_user WHERE email = '$email'");
    $registro = mysqli_num_rows ($sql);
    while ($line = mysqli_fetch_array ($sql)){
        $senha_user = $line ['senha'];
    }
    if ($registro){
        if($senha_user == $senha){
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['login'] = $email;
            $_SESSION['password'] = $senha;





        }else{
            echo "Senha invalida.";
            echo "<a href= 'login.php'>Tente novamente.</a>";
        }
    }else{
        echo "Você não possui cadastro. Deseja se cadastrar?";
        echo "<a href= 'form_cadastro.php'>Cadastre-se</a>";
    }

}else {
    header('location:login.php?valor=1');
}
```

**Os 3 newuser so logam com a senha criptografada**
[image: **Foto mysql**]

Comment: Está tentando logar com qual dos emails cadastrados?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/312913/verificar-hash-de-senha-no-login-password-hash

Comment: Primeiro eu testei com o newuser1@gmail.com, depois eu criei os outros newusers pra ver se eu tava errando a senha msm, mas só conseguir logar usando $argon2i$...

Comment: Você verificou o link que lhe enviei?

Comment: O erro é que você está comparando a senha criptografada com a senha normal, o correto seria você comparar a senha na query e não usando o PHP.
Ex.: `SELECT * FROM tb_user WHERE email = '$email' AND senha = '$senha';`
E antes de passar a senha para a query você precisa criptografar ela.
`$senha  = md5($_POST['senha']);` supondo q vc tenha usado md5 no cadastro pra salvar a senha.

Comment: De acordo com o link que @MagicHat, enviou, no seu logar.php, na linha `if($senha_user == $senha)` você pode substituir por `if( password_verify ( $senha, $senha_user )  )`, aí você não criptografa sua senha que vai ser comparada, veja [esse](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.password-verify.php) exemplo

Comment: O grande efeito colateral de copiar e colar é que gera o hábito de não ler, e então tudo se torna mais difícil...

Comment: Antes mesmo de eu vir fazer essa pergunta nesse site eu tinha visto o link que o MagicHat me enviou, mas mesmo assim eu não sabia onde exatamente eu deveria colocar o password_verify, e da forma que o @adventistaam utilizou funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: Que bom que funcionu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com o link que [@MagicHat](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/45437/magichat) enviou nos comentários.

No seu logar.php, na linha

`if($senha_user == $senha)`

Você pode substituir por

`if( password_verify ( $senha, $senha_user ) )`

Neste caso você não criptografa sua `$senha` que vai ser comparada.

[Veja](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.password-verify.php) esse exemplo