# Problema com Php e mysql - Login simples

Tags: php, mysql

Boa noite!

Estou fazendo um site simples, na qual aparece uma caixa com usuário e senha que serão mandados pelo *form* através do método *post* para a pagina *valida.php*. Ao comparar o usuario e senha digitados pelo usuário, com o usuario e senha predefinidos num if/else, a pagina redireciona para a main.html, que é o correto. Entretanto, quando mudo o codigo para chegar diretamente no banco de dados, quando o usuário entra as credenciais e aperta o botão, ele é mandado para a mesma página.. Não consigo entender oque está errado...

Segue os códigos:

*index.php*

```
   <form class="login100-form validate-form" method="POST" action="valida.php">
```

```
<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input">
    <input class="input100" type="password" id="inputSenha" name="senha" placeholder="Digite a Senha" required>
    <span class="focus-input100" data-placeholder="&#xf191;"></span>
</div>

<div id="botao">
    <input type="submit" value="ENTRAR" name="botao" id="entrar" class="btn efeito efeito-1 botaoEnviar" style="color: black; font-weight: bold" autofocus>
</div>
```

*valida.php*

```
<?php

    include_once("conexao.php");
    if((isset($_POST['user'])) && isset($_POST['senha']))
    {

        $usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['user']);
        $senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['senha']);
        $senha = md5($senha);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_login WHERE user = '$usuario' && senha = '$senha' LIMIT 1";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

        if(empty($resultado))
        {
            $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "Usuario ou senha incorretos.";
            header("Location: index.php");
        }
        elseif(isset($resultado))
        {
            header("Location: main.html");
        }
        else
        {
            $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "Usuario ou senha incorretos.";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "Usuario ou senha incorretos.";
        header("Location: index.php");
    }

?>
```

*conexao.php*

```
<?php
    $servidor = "localhost";
    $usuario  = "root";
    $senha = "";
    $dbname = "bd_otica";

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $dbname);

    if(!$conn)
    {
        die("Falha na conexão: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }else
    {}

?>
```

Obrigado por qualquer ajuda!

Comment: "_chegar diretamente no banco de dados_"... o que isso quer dizer? Não entendi...

Comment: Esse `LIMIT 1` também é estranho. Pode ter mais de 1 usuário com o mesmo nome de usuário e a mesma senha?

Comment: quanto ao chegar diretamente, quis dizer buscar no banco de dados a senha e o usuario do administrador.. Não pode ter mais que um usuário com o mesmo nome e a mesma senha, devo tirar esse LIMIT 1?

Comment: Claro, naõ serve pra nada rs

Comment: Fiz a alteração.. nada mudou, continua indo para index.php independente da senha/usuario

Comment: Pra um login simples seu código está extremamente complicado. sugiro uma pesquisada em login em mysql e php, tem exemplos prontos melhores no site. já de cara adianto, se for insistir na solução atual troque seu && por AND no select, tire esse monte de IF e ELSE e simplesmente verifique se o numero de linhas retornadas é maior que um, em vez desse fetch. O ideal mesmo sera usar password_verify https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/17005/70

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Como comentou o @Bacco, troque o `&&` por `AND` no SQL.

O `empty($resultado)` sempre vai ser *false* porque o `$resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);` vai retornar uma array, mesmo que o resultado da consulta do usuário e senha retorne uma array vazia.

Faça a penas um `if` e `else` se o comando `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` for verdadeiro, ou seja, achou algo no banco que coincide com o nome de usuário e senha:

```
if(mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
   header("Location: main.html");
}else{
   $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "Usuario ou senha incorretos.";
   header("Location: index.php");
}
```

Código completo:

```
<?php
    include_once("conexao.php");
    if((isset($_POST['user'])) && isset($_POST['senha']))
    {

        $usuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['user']);
        $senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['senha']);
        $senha = md5($senha);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tb_login WHERE user = '$usuario' AND senha = '$senha'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        if(mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            header("Location: main.html");
        }else{
            $_SESSION['loginErro'] = "Usuario ou senha incorretos.";
            header("Location: index.php");
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!!!! Resolveu o problema sim.. Como deu pra ver, não manjo muito de php, muito menos de banco de dados, ai esse projeto caiu em minhas mãos.. Agradeço o tempo gasto em me ajudar!

Answer (score 0):

O teu problema nesse sistema amigo @Cayo Eduardo Silveira, se deve apenas ao fato de que o código do formulário que voce postou na pergunta, ele não tem o campo "user" que é verificado na primeira condição `if((isset($_POST['user'])) && isset($_POST['senha']))`, dai o código direciona para o ultimo `else`, assim não satisfaz condição e consequentemente ele redireciona para `$_SESSION['loginErro'] = "Usuario ou senha incorretos.";header("Location: index.php");`

verifica ai e avisa

Comment: É que eu não coloquei o código completo, mas tem sim o campo user.. Obrigado mesmo assim